# jPlayer + Rails 3.1.3 swfPath?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jplayer

---

I am trying to get jPlayer working with the flash fallback in a rails app and so far no luck!  My constructor right now looks like this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
preload: "auto",
errorAlerts: true,
swfPath: "javascripts",
solution: "flash, html",
supplied: "oga",
wmode: "window",
ended: function(e) {
        ...some function...
}
});
```

I cannot get the swfPath correct it seems, and I must be missing something here about how jPlayer is looking for that path.  My other assets, such as images from stylesheets, seem to be correctly routed to the assets folder/images folder.  I can't seem to find the magic combination to get jPlayer to find the Jplayer.swf.  I have tried putting the swf file in the public folder, in a folder within the public folder, in the assets folder, and in the javascripts folder within the assets folder.  No luck!  Has anybody dealt with this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem... After finding no answer on the Internet, I started trying stuff :)

This worked for me (Rails 3.2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#jplayer").jPlayer({
       ready: function (event) {
           $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
               m4a: "url goes here"
           });
       },
       swfPath: "/",
       supplied: "m4a",
       solution: "flash, html"
   });
});
```

or in coffeescript:

```
$ = jQuery
$ ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $("#jplayer").jPlayer(
      ready: (event) ->
        $(this).jPlayer "setMedia",
          m4a: "url goes here"
      preload: "auto",
      swfPath: "/",
      solution: "html, flash",
      supplied: 'm4a')
```

I placed the Jplayer.swf file under public/.  Works now!

Answer (score 1):

I think a nifty way of doing this is to add a `swf` dir to the asset pipeline.

You can do this by adding

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "swf")
```

to your `config/application.rb` file and drop the `Jplayer.swf` file in `vendor/swf/Jplayer.swf`

In your JS file you import this by using `.js.erb`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jplayer").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "<%= asset_path "Jplayer.swf" %>"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has mentioned it here yet, you can also do it like this in your jplayer initialization code:

Works with Rails >= 3.2 that uses the asset pipeline!

```
swfPath: "<%= escape_javascript(asset_path('jplayer/Jplayer.swf')) %>",
solution: "flash,html",
supplied: "rtmpa,mp3",
```

And remember the file has a capital J :-)